# Running count of group joined data items in a query

Tags: reporting, cognos, cognos-11

Let's say I have two queries in Cognos Analytics which I am going to join

**Query A:** Employees

```
eID | Name | Department |
----|------|------------|
1   | Jim  | Sales      |
2   | Leo  | Sales      |
```

**Query B:** Violations

```
eID  | Violations |
---- |------------|
1    | ABC        |
1    | DEF        |
1    | GHI        | 
2    | JKL        |
2    | MNO        |
2    | PQR        |
```

When I join the data I need running counts, well running counts is easy but I need running count of joined or should I say grouped joined items. Let me explain what I mean

```
eID | SNo | Name  | Department | Sub-SNo | Violations |
----|-----|-------|------------|---------|------------|
e1  | 1   | Jim   | Sales      | 1       | ABC        |
e1  | 1   | Jim   | Sales      | 2       | DEF        |
e1  | 1   | Jim   | Sales      | 3       | GHI        |
e2  | 2   | Leo   | Sales      | 1       | JKL        |
e2  | 2   | Leo   | Sales      | 2       | MNO        |
e2  | 2   | Leo   | Sales      | 3       | PQR        |
```

In the above you can see that I have two serial numbers, `SNo` which can be easily done with running count function in the query. Any idea how I can do `Sub-SNo`

p.s I am not writing SQL queries, I am using GUI query builder

[image]

[image]

Comment: try this: running-count([Violations] for [Eid],[SNo],[Department])

Answer (score 0):

I'll keep the what seems to me to be my obligatory *you really ought to think about doing some of that modelling in the modelling tool* to a minimum.

I'm not quite sure what you want to do but have you looked at the *for* operator?

Running-count ( Sub-SNo for SNo)   for example.